# Assign Python variables from Excel spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel

I want to create a Python script to have my wallpaper changed based on some specific times (sunset and sunrise to be more precise), with 2 pictures alternating between night and day.

For the wallpaper change part I've managed to put something together which kind of works, but now I've hit an wall and I don't know which way to go.

I have an Excel spreadsheet with 3 columns (`day_of_year` *-containing dates-*, `sunrise` *-containing time-*, `sunset` *-containing time-*), and I want to have 2 variables created in Python (`sunrise_today` and `sunset_today`) which will bring me from the spreadsheet the corresponding values for today. In Excel environment this would be called a `VLOOKUP` using `TODAY()` as key.

This is pretty much what I want:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried using Pandas to imput the spreadsheet?  Pandas has all kinds of utilities for handling date/time data.

Comment: A little off-topic: You can compute the sun rise and set times in Python and forget about the spreadsheet. See my answer to the question [Javascript or Python - How do I figure out if it's night or day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15044521/javascript-or-python-how-do-i-figure-out-if-its-night-or-day)

Comment: @martineau Thank you for the input. The thing is I would want to use some official/published data for civil sunrise/sunset based on a specific location.  I've tried several options so far that can answer my questions, but sadly haven't found anything (there is always a difference of 1 to 10 minutes between the published data and the output).

Comment: The code in my answer will work for any location given its longitude and latitude (plus timezone). However I understand needing to read the spreadsheet if you are wanting to use some sort of published data. Note there are a number of third-party modules available that provide ways of reading (and writing) xlsx format files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should pull the proper row with minimal fuss.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas

file_path = "Your_Excel_File.xls"
data = pandas.read_excel(file_path, header=0) #I assume the column names are on line 0

#Find today as day of year
day = datetime.now().timetuple().tm_yday

#Grab today's info
sunrise = data["sunrise"][day-1] #Minus 1 to account for 0 based indexing
sunset = data["sunset"][day-1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Everything is clear and concise. However, I tried your approach and I got the following Syntax error. For some reason I think it's something I'm missing regarding the way I should be approaching the file_path. 
**File "<ipython-input-11-97ec4e4dbc3a>", line 4
    file_path = "C:\Users\mariu\Desktop\DateTime.xlsx"
                ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape**

Comment: @instaspam: FYI, you can use a limited version of markdown to format your questions, comment, and answers quite nicely. [Here's some formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Coming back to finally close the topic. Apparently there was a typo in my code where I called the column headers "Sunrise" and "Sunset", with capital letters, and in the function they were called "sunset" and "sunrise" (lowercase). I re-checked my code, changed the header names to better fit the code, all good now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the best way, but you can do it using pandas and openpyxl:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

xls_file = "YourFile.xls"
xls_sheet = "YourSheet"
XLSXreader=pd.ExcelFile(xls_file, engine = 'openpyxl')
INP_Data = pd.read_excel(XLSXreader,sheet_name=xls_sheet,eader=1)
```

This will generate a INP_Data, which is a Pandas dataframe. You cn access the values by:

```
INP_Data['YourHeaderName']
```

You can convert it to numpy array by:

```
INP_Data['YourHeaderName'].to_numpy()
```

Check which line is your current date:

```
Date_Line = INP_Data['YourHeaderName'].to_numpy() == YourCurrentDate
```

And then get the Rising Time by

```
RisingTime = INP_Data['RisinTimeHeader'].to_numpy()[Date_Line]
```

Note: take a look at the pd.read_excel function in order to define the header lines and columns you want to read.

Hope to help someway. Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This would be a great starting point. I will test this out and come back with a feedback.